# How to efficiently find separately for each element N maximum values among multiple matrices?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, memory-efficient

I am looping through a large number of H x W matrices. I cannot store them all in memory. I need to get N matrices. For example, the element of the 1st of N matrix in position (i, j) will be the largest among all elements in position (i, j) of all processed matrix matrices. For the second of the N matrix, the elements that are the second-largest will be taken, and so on.

Example.

[image] [image] [image]

Let N = 2. Then the 1st matrix will look like this.

[image]

And the second matrix is like this.

[image]

How to do such an operation inside a loop so as not to store all matrices in memory?

Comment: Do you want to sort the matrices?

Comment: @Kevin, I do not understand your question. This problem can be solved by sorting all matrices and taking a slice. But the problem is that all the matrices have to be stored in memory. And it is possible to find N = const maxima in one pass of the loop, in contrast to sorting.

Comment: Looks like it's `H x W` [k-largest elements in a stream](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-largest-element-in-a-stream/).

Comment: @QuangHoang, yes you are right. I can even try to implement a naive algorithm. But numpy allows you to conveniently and efficiently vectorize operations, and I would like to know a simple but effective solution.

Comment: I think this can be done with ```np.partition```. It will do a partial sort on the matrices.

Comment: There is [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) but that requires putting everything on the memory as well. I don't think `np` has any advantage on stream data.

Comment: Also, [pytorch's `topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.topk.html) which allows you to take `k` largest elements along a dimention. But again, only works when you have things in memory.

Comment: Among the values `7, 3, 7`, is the second-largest value 7 or 3?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, 7.

Comment: @КириллМалышев according to your constraints, is it possible to have ```HxWxN``` items in memory at a time?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, of course. The result of this size is what you need to get. In my answer, I use an even larger buffer.

Comment: @КириллМалышев I have posted an answer. Please time it and let us know about the performance of it.

Comment: keep `KW` min-heaps in memory each storing `N` elements (I assume `N` is much smaller than the very large number of matrices you have.) Run each heap concurrently tracking `N` elements. Loop over all matrices once. This is an O(KW N log(N) ) solution, you'd be hard-pressed to do better.

Comment: @ldog, N = 7. K is the height? I'm afraid I can't run 442368 threads in parallel.

Comment: @КириллМалышев: yes sorry K is supposed to be H, mistype. That's fine, just use a thread-pool like any sane multi-threaded application would (recycle threads to do concurrent work at maximally concurrent load for the hardware system.)

Comment: @ldog, thanks for the recommendations. The solution from my answer works and allows me to compute the result in a reasonable amount of time. I think I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments suggested using the `np.partition` function. I replaced the use of numpy with [cupy](https://cupy.dev/), which uses the GPU. And also added a buffer to sort less frequently.

```
import cupy as np

buf = // # As much as fits into the GPU
largests = np.zeros((buf + N, h, w))
for i in range(num):
    val = //
    largests[i % buf] = val
    if i % buf == buf - 1:
        largests.partition(range(buf, buf + N), axis=0)
largests.partition(range(buf, buf + N), axis=0)  # Let's not forget the tail
res = largests[:-(N + 1):-1]
```

The solution does not work very quickly, but I have come to terms with this speed.